# What does randomly initialized data mean for heap memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory, vector, heap-memory

As I read,
`int x[50];` 
is initialized on the stack in order.
`int* x = (int*) malloc(50*sizeof(int)) ;`
is initialized on the heap randomly(?).
So my question is that, does randomly means that this 50 integers can be stored not in line?

I mean, 20integers can be in line, other 25 are in line at another memory adress and the other 5 integers are in another memory location?

And one last thing, everytime we resize the array with realloc, it copies all the data to new place that is big enough for new size, so does it work also for vectors in C++ either created on the heap or stack?

thank you for your reply.

Comment: The 50 integers on the heap are allocated contiguously. The exact spot in the heap is not necessarily the same from run to run, and can't be relied upon. Although depending on your implementation (compiler and system) it MAY be the same location. Some embedded devices certainly allocate memory especially on startup in a pretty predictable way. Still shouldn't be relied on though.

Comment: As for your `vector` question: if you're using `vector`, you shouldn't be allocating space for an array of `vector`s on the heap. You should make a `vector` of `vector`s. You'll know when you need to do manual memory management. And when that time comes you'll know what to do.

Comment: The `int`s are allocated in order (conitgously), but their content is random, in the sense that it will just be whatever memory happens to be at that spot, interpreted as an `int`.

Comment: @melk: Uninitialized objects in C have indeterminate values. They may act as if they do not have a fixed stored value, and whatever value they do appear to have might not be the value in the memory allocated for them. In other words, the contents of an allocated array are not reliably whatever happens to be in memory.

Comment: @melk could you please open more your saying " content is random" please?

Comment: @Wokers: When you do not initialize something, its value is uncontrolled (by you or the software you write). Some people describe this as “random,” but that is sloppy language; “random” has a different meaning in technical contexts, related to probability and unknowability. Since you are not controlling the value, the object may take on values that are in its memory from previous use or, depending on how the C implementation operates, from processor registers or other things. The C standard allows a variety of things to happen. Generally, it is a mistake to use uninitialized objects.